# Perl Rest Web Service Parameters

Tags: perl, rest, parameter-passing

I am trying to call REST web service as follows:

```
my $client = REST::Client->new();

$client->setHost("http://myhost.com");

$client->POST('/xx/yy/Submit',
              $params,
              {'Content-type' => 'application/json'}
             );

my $response = $client->responseContent();
```

I do not how to create parameter list, api definition is as follows:

```
{
    "Credential": {
            "Username": "String",
            "Password": "String"
    },
    "DataCoding": "Default",
    "Header": {
            "From": "String",
            "ValidityPeriod": 0
    },
    "Message": "String",
    "To": ["String"]
}
```

I tried following but did not work:

```
my %params = (Credential => {
                                Username => $username,
                                Password => $password
                            },
              DataCoding => 'Default',
              Header     => {
                                From => $from,  
                                ValidityPeriod => 0         
                            },              
              Message  => "Test",
              To       => ['90535xxxx','90542xxxxx']
           );

$client->POST('/v1/xml/syncreply/Submit',
              encode_json(\%params),
              {'Content-type' => 'application/json',
                'Accept' => 'application/json'
              }
             );
```

It gives following error:

```
<ErrorCode>SerializationException</ErrorCode>
Error: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type Barabut.Gw.Submit. The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. ---&amp;gt; System.Xml.XmlException: The data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Comment: Use a hash of hashes, serialize to JSON via a proper module ([JSON::PP](http://p3rl.org/JSON::PP) is in core).

Comment: It should be `To => [ '90535xxxx' ]`, but it doesn't seem to be the reason of the failure.

Comment: @choroba, I realized it and sent array as 'To' parameter. I see that my encoded json data is correct but it still gives error

Comment: The error suggests the system tried to decode the data as XML, not JSON.

Comment: @choroba it worked when I wrote endpoint correct :)

Answer (score -1):

I wrote end-point address incorrect, it worked at the format I wrote, sorry for this situation.